# counting characters in an array

Tags: c

If I have an array of words, such as:

```
char words[2][10] = {"One","Two","Three"};
```

How could I count the individual characters of each string?

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` is the function that computes the length of a string.

And quoting the standard:

> The length of a string is the number of bytes preceding the null character.

Answer (score 0):

You may be encountering problems because the dimensions of your array are incorrect (2 instead of 3). The initializer "Three" is being discarded. You can use this syntax to automatically infer the correct dimension from the initializer list:

```
char words[][10] = {"One","Two","Three"};
```

Now "strlen(words[2])" will reliably produce the correct result.